# Find best Ready-made Analyzer/Tokenizer/TokenFilters for Solr that divide input string

Tags: solr, analyzer

I am moving some existing Index from Lucene to Solr. We apply the following Logic on the Input text in Lucene:

1. to lower case
2. replaceDictionaryWords (replace some specific words by other words example replace "hertz" by "htz")
3. extract characters and digits only
4. trim output string
5. replace \s+ by \s
6. split using java.lang.String#split(in) method
7. for each splitted text, divide the result word by the following pattern: "ABCDEF" => ABC BCD CDE DEF (divide on 3, 2)

I don't want to write Tokenizer that might be exist.

So, I looked here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters but get missed.

Answer (score 1):

1. [LowerCaseFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory),
2. [SynonymFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory),
3. [StandardTokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory) or [PatternTokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory),
4. [TrimFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.TrimFilterFactory),
5. [PatternReplaceFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory),
6. [WordDelimiterFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory)?
7. [NGramTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html) (you may need to write a factory for this one).

But if you already have an existing Lucene analyzer, you can [make Solr use it](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Analyzer).

Answer (score 0):

Try [OpenPipeline](http://openpipeline.org). It's designed for preprocessing documents that get fed to search software.

Comment: Create your own stage that pushes items into Solr.